# Codeigniter Issue with SQL COUNT & JOIN

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I have an issue with counting the rows joined in SQL (Latest Version).

I have my main Table say `matches`.

```
id     match_name

1      match 1
2      match 2
3      match 3
4      match 4
```

I have another table `match_entries`.

```
id    user_id    match_id    registration_success

1     56         1          true
2     29         1          true
3     24         1          true
```

My requirement will be to show all the matches and the number of entries registered under each match.
My SQL code is :

```
    $this->db->select('m.id, count(e.id) AS total_entries'); 
    $this->db->from('matches m'); 
    $this->db->join('match_entries e', "m.id=e.match_id",'LEFT'); 
    $this->db->group_by('e.match_id');
    $this->db->order_by('m.id', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $row = $query->result();

    if (empty($row))
        return FALSE;
    return $row;
```

**Result I get**

```
[{"id":"1","total_entries":"3"},{"id":"2","total_entries":"0"}]
```

The above code works without any errors. The major problem here is, the result shows only 2 rows from the `matches` table instead it should show 4 with `total_entries` "0" in other rows.

What is wrong with the code? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Change `group_by('e.match_id')` to `group_by('m.id')`.

Comment: Perfect! Worked.

Comment: The reason why it worked is because when you do a `left` join, you need to group by `m.id` since not all `e.match_id` is present in `m.id`. Hence, you were missing out on those which are not present.